# Fastest way to get to a parent in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to assign a style to a table with the class "tableClass". I have the following markup.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableClass">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableClass"> <-- Need to add a style here
      <tr class="colheadrowclass">
        .. some markup here
      </tr>
      more markup
      <tr id="dataRow" class="datarowclass">
      </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From the `datarowclass`, I need to traverse up to the first table with the class `tableClass` and add a style to it.

This works for me, but I was wondering if there's a faster way.

```
$(".datarowclass").parents("table").eq(0).css("hieght", "500px");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help you:

```
$('.datarowclass').closest('table.tableClass').css("height", "500px");
```

It does exactly what you mentioned:

1. Selects element with `datarowclass` class.
2. From it (the element found in point 1.) searches up to the closest `table` with `tableClass` class,
3. Changes style of the element found in point 2.

**Note**: You had a **typo** in the "`height`" property (you misspelled it as "`hieght`").

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.closest()` and get rid of `.eq(0)`.

```
$(".datarowclass").closest("table").css("hieght", "500px");
```